# Correction on code of c++

Tags: c++

I want to copy one string to other string. Suppose I have one string "happy day" in one       variable then it should be copied in other variable as "happyday". I tried following code but its  not working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int count=0;

void main()
{
    char a[20],b[20];
    int i=0,j=0;

    clrscr();

    cin>>a;
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        b[j]=a[i];
        count++;
        i++;j++;
    }
    i++;
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        b[j]=a[i];
        count++;
        i++;j++;
    }

    cout<<count<<"\n";
    cout<<b;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about "is not working". Give error messages, expected and actual output.

Comment: I don't see no happy days in the code. No checking for space characters. `i` is incremented to oblivion and second loop is pointless.

Comment: i gave the string happy days as e.g. And the expected output is that the string should be copied in b variable as "happydays" without the blank space between two words "happy days"

Comment: @user3464773 i was being sarcastic...

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to use the algorithm `remove_if` and `isspace`:

```
remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace);
```

`remove_if` will make at most one copy of the data

Reference on [isspace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace) and include `ctype.h`. I think you might also have to add a `::` to the beginning of `isspace`.

Answer (score 1):

1. The second while loop is not necessary and even plain wrong.
2. You don't copy the terminating zero.
3. You dont bother for spaces while copying
4. reading with cin will stop at first space

This works :

```
void main()
{
    char a[20], b[20];

    fgets(a, 20, stdin) ;

    char c ;
    int i = 0, j = 0;    
    do 
    {
        c = a[i++] ; 

        if (c != ' ')
           b[j++] = c;

    } while (c != '\0') ;

    cout << i << "\n";
    cout << b;

    getch();
}
```

Comment: I m saying that i want to copy the string char by char and remove the space between two words and then copy